# Why does a cosine function have a non-infinite Fourier coefficient?

Tags: dsp, fourier, signal-theory

I took my signals class a long time ago and have gotten used to using Fourier tables for a lot of things. I'm reading a textbook on communications and I stared at the Fourier transform equation for a bit too long because now I'm confused at a very basic level. If we have a signal \$f(t)\$ that consists only of a cosine with frequency \$\omega\$, whenever we integrate that signal with the complex phasor of the Fourier transform, the \$e^{-j\omega t}\$, will that complex phasor not perfectly "rectify" the signal, resulting in an integration from \$(-\infty, \infty)\$ of a function that is only positive, resulting in an infinite coefficient? Why do we instead get the dirac delta as the result of this integration?

If we wrote out the \$e^{-j\omega t}\$ part of the Fourier transform as a cosine plus an imaginary sin, the cosine squared term that will be present when multiplied by \$f(t)\$ is going to be only positive for all values t. How does this not result in a Fourier coefficient with an amplitude of infinity? I feel like I'm missing something very very simple.

Comment: But the dirac delta *is* infinitely high. What's the problem?

Comment: That's the simple thing I was missing, I had forgotten the dirac is infinite. I think I was remembering the property of it having an area of one as it having an amplitude of one.

Comment: @CEEA That's the key! Cool that you got it so quickly from Dave's comment!

Comment: I never even learned what a Fourier coefficient was in my signals class.

Comment: `will that complex phasor not perfectly "rectify" the signal` - nothing rectified or looking like rectification in this process.

Comment: @Andyaka: Have you never seen what happens when you multiply two sine waves of the same frequency and phase with each other? You get a component at 2x the frequency, and another component that's constant -- i.e., DC. This is the "rectification" that the OP is referring to.

Comment: @DaveTweed of course but it doesn't look like rectification - it's a sinewave of twice the frequency set at a DC offset.

Comment: @Andyaka  the product looks exactly like FW rectification.  . the null is at the zero crossing not the negative peak of 2f , offset by DC.

Comment: Selective moderator action has been taken to move comments inside 3 sigma acceptability boundaries :-).